# setInterval and clearInterval with same button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hey i was just wondering would there be away for me for setInterval and clearInterval with only one button?

```js
var checkExist;

function checkOn() {
  checkOff();
  checkExist = setInterval(function() {
    if ($('#advert').css('display') == 'block')
      $('#statsContinue').trigger('click');
  }, 1000); // Speed for check 
}

function checkOff() {
  if (checkExist !== null) {
    clearInterval(checkExist);
    checkExist = null;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button onclick="checkOn();" style="">Skip Stats On</button>
<button onclick="checkOff();" style="">Skip Stats Off</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Validate if the `checkExist` is null or not to take what action like this:

```js
var checkExist = null;

function toggle_check() {
  clearInterval(checkExist);
  if (checkExist !== null) {
    checkExist = null;
  } else {
    checkExist = setInterval(function() {
      if ($('#advert').css('display') == 'block')
        $('#statsContinue').trigger('click');
        console.log('triggered!');
    }, 1000); // Speed for check 
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button onclick="toggle_check();" style="">Skip Stats On</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a quick workaround by adding a switch method checking if `checkExist` is null or not.

```js
const checkExist = null;

const checkOn = () => {
  checkExist = setInterval(function() {
    if ($('#advert').css('display') == 'block')
      $('#statsContinue').trigger('click');
  }, 1000); // Speed for check
};

const checkOff = () => {
  if (checkExist !== null) {
    clearInterval(checkExist);
    checkExist = null;
  }
};

const checkSwitch = () => {
  !checkExist ? checkOn() : checkOff();
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button onclick="checkSwitch();" style="">click me !</button>
```